# How to construct and update the members of nested class?

Tags: c#

We were using service references which provided api's to access the some functions with specific types,as those service references are no more available we are planning to have similar classes to make our code work

Service references provided Service type as follows

SearchService → SearchResponse → Fields

Which I feel is a nested class was trying to build the similar class .

```
public class SearchResponse_t
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string FieldValue { get; set; }
}

public class SearchResult_t
{
    public SearchResponse_t SearchResponse { get; set; }
}
```

I am novice to C#

I expected that when I create a new instance of  the `SearchResult_t` same will happen on the `SearchResponse_t`,but it seems that's not happening.

Comment: Note that that isn't a nested class. A nested class is a class whose type is declared within another class.

Comment: How should your program know that it should create a new instance of your response? What id your `SearchResponse`-class had some derived classes as well? How should your program knwo which of those to instantiate? You surely have to tell it to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a class is instantiated, its members (where you don't specify a default value) are initialized to `default(T)` where `T` is the type in question.

- For reference types `default(T)` is always null. Classes are reference types.
- For value types `default(T)` will provide their default value. For numeric types this is `0`, etc.

So to address your specific question: I would expect `SearchResponse` to be `null` after you construct `SearchResult_t`. If you want it to hold a new instance of `SearchResponse_t` you can instruct it to do that by default:

```
public class SearchResult_t
{
    public SearchResponse_t SearchResponse { get; set; } = new SearchResponse_t();
}
```

or you can add a constructor and initialize it there:

```
public class SearchResult_t
{
    public SearchResponse_t SearchResponse { get; set; }

    public SearchResult_t()
    {
        this.SearchResponse = new SearchResponse_t();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can do it after you instantiate the class:

```
SearchResult_t result = new SearchResult_t();
result.SearchResponse = new SearchResponse_t();
```

---

To address your expectation that `SearchResponse` would also be populated with a new instance, consider the following example:

```
public class Node<T>
{
    public Node<T> Previous { get; set; }
    public Node<T> Next { get; set; }
    public T Item { get; set; }
}
```

In this example, `Node<T>` references itself as `Previous` and `Next` values. If .NET were to also instantiate them, you would have an infinite loop. This isn't the only reason why things work like this, I imagine, but it's a good example of why they don't.

Comment: Thanks John,compiler is not allowing me have new instance of the SearchResponse_t with in SearchResult_t.it expects "Method must have return type"

Comment: @Phaneesh you must have done something wrong. Please look at my example again. It seems likely you added the `public SearchResult_t()` to your `SearchResponse_t` class by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for.

```
public class SearchResult_t
{
    private SearchResponse_t _searchResponse = new SearchResponse_t(); 

    public SearchResponse_t SearchResponse
    {
        get { return this._searchResponse; }
        set { this._searchResponse = value; }
    }
}
```